# Memory issues with N large matrices

Tags: python, memory-management, pytorch, tensor, large-data-volumes

I have to create N large matrices, of size M x M, with M = 100'000, on a cluster. I can create them one by one. Usually I would first define a tensor

```
mat_all = torch.zeros((N,M,M))
```

And then I would fill `mat_all` as follows:

```
for i in range(N):
    tmp = create_matrix(M,M)
    mat_all[i,:,:] = tmp
```

where the function `create_matrix` creates a square matrix of size M.

My problem is: if I do that, I have memory issue in creating the big tensor `mat_all` with `torch.ones` . I do not have these issues when I create the matrices one by one with `create_matrix`.

I was wondering if there is a way to have a tensor as `mat_all` which deals with N matrices MxM but in such a way that I do not have memory issues.

Comment: So by *creating the big tensor*, your very first line is the issue since you are assigning elements of tensor in loop? And what do you mean by *memory issues*? `MemoryError`? Did you isolate to these lines and not others in larger process?